# Powershell Import-CSV and Get-Aduser

Tags: powershell, syntax

I have a CSV File with a list of users.  There are two columns in the file: Surname and Name. I need to filter the users with a surname and from a particular OU.  I used this command but it's not working:

```
Import-CSV c:\work_sharepoint\output\DoublonsSharepointTest.csv | % { Get-ADUser -f "sn -eq $($_.Surname)" -Searchbase "OU=Portail_User_Sharepoint,OU=OU-SNE_SharePoint,DC=vnf,DC=local"}| Move-ADObject -TargetPath "ou=Disable Sharepoint Users,dc=vnf,dc=local"
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: (Unfortunately, I cannot help with Powershell, but ..) "Not working" is an ambiguous description. What *actually* happens instead of the expected result?

Comment: What kind of error you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the surname needs to be quoted e.g.:

```
... -f "sn -eq `"$($_.Surname)`"" ...
```

Comment: Darn, you beat me to it. I'd use single quotes for the nested quotes, though. Makes it easier to read.